# Checking if date delta between stored date delta

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date

I am building a booking system, where users must not be able to book overlapping another booking.

Three variables are provided, start date, end date, and product ID. I need to check that the gap between the start date and end date of the proposed booking does not overlap with an old booking.

Previously, I used MySQL's `BETWEEN`, but realised that that would only work if the user attempted to book within an existing booking, however if someone books earlier, ending later than an old one then it goes through.

```
private
function is_available($product, $from, $end)
{
  if (!$from || !$end) return false;
  global $wpdb;
  $table = $wpdb->prefix . "ovalbit_utils";
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE booking=$product AND ('$from' between `start` and `end`) OR ('$end' between `start` and `end`)";
  $rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  return ($rows == null) ? true : false;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a third OR clause, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE booking=$product AND (('$from' between `start` and `end`) OR ('$end' between `start` and `end`)) OR (('$from'<`start`) AND ('$end'>`end`)) ";
```

Answer (score 1):

//try this query

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE booking=$product AND (('$from' between `start` and `end`) OR ('$end' between `start` and `end`))";